# Why would a whole region have severe difficulties with the railway "signalling system"?

Tags: communication, signal

The background for my question is that Oslo Central Station, Norway's main railway station, and the surrounding area keeps getting closed because of "signalling errors".

The railway authority always simplify their explanations like this:

> There is a complete stoppage of all trains on Oslo S (central station) due to signal
>   problems. The railway authority is working to correct the error. Delays
>   will unfortunately occur.

The main newspaper in Oslo, Aftenposten, in the most recent case added some information by saying it was a "ground error" causing the shut down.

Now, the vagueness intrigues me and I would really like to know if any of you have theories on what the cause of this would be, or experience working with railway systems.

**What could be the cause of the multiple massive shut downs of railway traffic in the Oslo area?**

Comment: Poor maintenance of 'proven technology from the seventies', let me think if I can come up with a country that has similar problems ...

Comment: In a railway system I'd expect "proven technology from the 70's" to refer to the 1870's...And electrical systems to be more like proven technology from the 1920's.

Comment: But maybe that reflects the fact I'm more familiar with American rail systems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the Oslo area uses a [Third Rail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_rail) system, and that a "ground error" was mentioned makes me suspect the issue is not just signalling errors, but current leakage problems from the third rail, or possibly conductor segment connection issues causing voltage drops.

This maybe caused by snow/ice/leaves building up, or the insulation breaking down in some way. It's possible this is also related to the signalling errors (i.e. causing them) if they use the same return path.

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be a minor one with just a couple of signals, but the complete shutdown of that part of the network is a safety measure.

Trains should stop at red lights. New systems will do this automatically, but for instance in Belgium it was only introduced in all trains after a few bad accidents had happened with many casualties. If the automatic stop system isn't implemented yet and just signal doesn't work or work reliably the red light might not show, the train won't stop and may crash into another one.

The reason of the failing signaling could be anything, it's no use speculating without further details.